# Table - Head on left, content on right both in one vertical line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table whose column header is on the left side of the cell and the content on the right but in one vertical line. Picture for example - [image](https://i.ibb.co/f0ksdND/example.jpg)

I've tried with padding, margin and white-space

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.one {
  width: 75%;
}

.two {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
}

.two button:first-child{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.two button:last-child {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Title One</td>
      <td>
        <p>Title Two</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Lorem</td>
      <td class="two">
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Currently the result looks like: [http://jsfiddle.net/paciek/Lzdb3uhp/12/
I expect the look as in the attached picture. Of course, without the green line that explains the problem. It would be nice if it could be easily converted into RWD.

Answer (score 0):

gave the width to the td and commented `margin-left` of the button. hope this helps thanks.
remove margin of both button. and add align="right" to the Title Two `td`

ref below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/g90ny61j/

```css
.title-one{width:81%}

.container {
  width: 600px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.one {
  width: 75%;
}

.two {
  width: 25%;
  /*text-align: right;*/
}

.two button:first-child{
 /*  margin-left: 20px; */
}

.two button:last-child {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="title-one">Title One</td>
      <td align="left">
        <p>Title Two</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Lorem</td>
      <td class="two" align="left">
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That page doesn't exist.

Comment: its opening please check again

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution, check image in post.

Comment: @KamilPaciepnik i have updated my answer. check the link now. i will edit description if this is what you are looking for. thanks

Comment: check now.. i have uncommented it. an if this fixes it the please mark it as answered. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer!

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.one {
  width: 75%;
}

.two {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
}

.two button:first-child{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.two button:first-child {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.container table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}
.container table tr td button {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Title One</td>
      <td>
        <p>Title Two</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Lorem</td>
      <td class="two">
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need button on right side with right space, and title above.

Comment: @KamilPaciepnik updated my answer please check if you are looking for this

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, I did not mean this effect - check image [https://i.ibb.co/f0ksdND/example.jpg]

Comment: @KamilPaciepnik check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use below style to align your  with content "Title two" :

```
td p{
margin-left: 29px;}
```